# declarative_authorization and authlogic problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, declarative-authorization

(Disclaimer: I am very new to rails)

This plugin looks like it will be a great fit for my app, but I am
having a hard time getting it to work. I am using it with authlogic, I
am not sure if that is the problem, but it seems like it may be.

When I try an access a page that my admin role should have access to I
get this:

```
Processing CompaniesController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-02-12
23:26:44) [GET]
Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"companies",
"battalion_id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.000681)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" =
'147') LIMIT 1
User Update (0.000622)   UPDATE "users" SET "perishable_token" =
'tUyTl1eZDQSJwp_PFw7c', "last_request_at" = '2010-02-13 05:26:44',
"updated_at" = '2010-02-13 05:26:44' WHERE "id" = 147
Role Load (0.000334)   SELECT * FROM "roles" WHERE ("roles".user_id
= 147)
Permission denied: No matching rules found for show for #<User id:
147, user_type: nil, login: "lauren_roth", name: "Lauren
Rothlisberger", email: "laurenrothlisber...@gmail.com",
crypted_password:
"d835a2cdf15ef449d0980e706fd86d7a9a7a0a23d0d79d6f18f...",
 password_salt: "_Qz_z8eZOhKHcsPsBsoP", created_at: "2010-02-12
 16:37:53", updated_at: "2010-02-13 05:26:44", old_remember_token: nil,
 old_remember_token_expires_at: nil, old_activation_code: nil,
 activated_at: nil, old_password_reset_code: nil, enabled: true,
 identity_url: nil, invitation_id: nil, invitation_limit: nil,
 position: "Admin", battalion_id: nil, company_id: nil, soldier_id:
 nil, login_count: 68, failed_login_count: 0, last_request_at:
 "2010-02-13 05:26:44", current_login_at: "2010-02-13 05:20:59",
 last_login_at: "2010-02-13 05:19:57", current_login_ip: "127.0.0.1",
 last_login_ip: "127.0.0.1", persistence_token:
 "28fc9b60853045cd4e43a001b4258940a7e8f9ac50b08df6a6d...",
 single_access_token: "bKgYvuRtLqauufljZDoV", perishable_token:
 "tUyTl1eZDQSJwp_PFw7c", active: true, platoon_id: nil> (roles
 [:Admin], privileges [:show], context :companies).
 Filter chain halted as [:filter_access_filter] rendered_or_redirected.
 Completed in 27ms (View: 1, DB: 0 3 queries) | 403 Forbidden [http://
 localhost/battalions/1/companies/1]
```

I have this in my User model
     def role_symbols
       (roles || []).map {|r| r.name.to_sym}
     end

But it doesn't seem to be calling that. I *think* that may be the
heart of the problem, but I am also wondering if it has anything to do
with the user_sessions?

Also this is what my application_controller looks like:

```
 helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
 filter_parameter_logging :password, :password_confirmation

  before_filter :set_current_user
  protected
  def set_current_user
    Authorization.current_user = current_user
  end

  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined? (@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
  end

  def redirect_back_or_default(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end


Here is my authorization_rules.rb
```

I did capitalize the Admin to reflect that:

```
authorization do
   role :guest do
    has_permission_on :user_sessions, :to => [:create, :update]
   end

   role :Admin do
     has_permission_on :companies, :to => [:index, :show]
   end
 end
```

If you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the application loads the rules of table **roles** properly, but don't load the config/authorization_rules.rb file correctly. Please check the file, his name and the syntax used.

Try to use the **privileges** section in *authorization_rules.rb*; like this:

```
privileges do
  privilege :manage, :includes => [:create, :read, :update, :delete]
  privilege :read, :includes => [:index, :show]
  privilege :create, :includes => :new
  privilege :update, :includes => :edit
  privilege :delete, :includes => :destroy
end
```

---

And what about the Companies controller?

---

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> I did capitalize the Admin to reflect that

What do you mean by that? The admin role should be capitalized in the `authorization_rules.rb` file as the `role_symbols` method seems to be working and is returning `[:Admin]` as an array of user roles. You can see that in the log:

> `(roles [:Admin], privileges [:show], context :companies)`

This means that the current user has the roles specified, but needs at least one of the listed privileges to access the context/resource. So your `authorization_rules.rb` has to have a capitalized role `:Admin`.

Comment: Yes, I did you can see the last thing I listed was the authorization_rules and :Admin is capitalized, just as the Role is in the Roles table. I just can't seem to figure out where this is going wrong.